# How to proxy a web request and forward it accurately

Tags: django, apache, http, proxy, vpn

I'm trying to proxy the HTTP connections to a website, so that I can always access it from the same IP address of my server, from any device in the world. I am trying to do it without any installations or browser configurations like proxies.

So I want to go to mydomain.com/asd and it to load targetwebsite.com/asd perfectly normal, like a VPN that's browser based. It will always be used for the same target domain, although the page does load contents from other domains.

I don't really know if there's an easy nginx/httpd config I could do to do this, so I just tried to do it in Django.

```
def index(request):
    url = "https://targetwebsite.com" + request.META['PATH_INFO']

    if request.method == 'GET':
        r = requests.get(url)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        r = requests.post(url)

    return HttpResponse(r.text)
```

This works, sometimes. There are some weird Javascript errors, the odd 404. Is there anything that this code is missing?

One idea:

- shared/static session cookie between all requests, so login can be made

Comment: If the site using `/` or `/static` for pointing static asset then most likely will not work because once it render on the frontend it will start looking static asset in your website instead of `targetwesite`. One possible way to do this by creating your own parser  like it can convert static url to targetwebiste static. Our of curious did you try shareurl.in?

Comment: @RajaSimon I changed to `STATIC_URL = '/statichome/'` - forgot to mention that. Not sure what `shareurl.in` is.

Comment: Nooo, what I'm trying to say is you're returning hole target site as string as response. Now, what if the target site use relative URL ( href="/static/image.png" ) instead of full URL?